# Count words in table field

Tags: postgresql

I have this PostgreSQL table for storing words:

```sql
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS words
(
    id bigint NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('processed_words_id_seq'::regclass),
    keyword character varying(300) COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    keyword_count double precision
)

insert into words (words)
VALUES ('while swam is interesting');
```

How I can count the words in column `keyword` and insert the number into column `keyword_count` using SQL query?

Comment: I don't understand exactly, but this sounds like a bad design. Don't store redundant data.

Comment: Please provide example data to make your question clearer.

Comment: for example I have these words `while swam is interesting`. How I can count them?

Comment: Why is the keyword_count `DOUBLE PRECISION`? Counts are `INTEGER`s! Also, less space!

Comment: Good point. What would be the recommend filed type?

Comment: Counts are integers and don't have a fractional component!

Comment: I'd say `SMALLINT` (or `INT4`) to save space.

Answer (score 1):

One way to count the words separated by whitespaces :

```
SELECT ARRAY_LENGTH(REGEXP_SPLIT_TO_ARRAY(keyword, '\s'), 1)
FROM words ;
```

As per *insert the number into column keyword_count using SQL query*, try:

```
UPDATE words set keyword_count = ARRAY_LENGTH(REGEXP_SPLIT_TO_ARRAY(keyword, '\s'), 1);
```

[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/qU39yaDC)

[regexp_split_to_array()](https://pgpedia.info/r/regexp_split_to_array.html#:%7E:text=regexp_split_to_array()%20is%20a%20system,was%20added%20in%20PostgreSQL%208.3.)

[array_length()](https://pgpedia.info/a/array_length.html#:%7E:text=array_length()%20is%20a%20system,was%20added%20in%20PostgreSQL%208.4.)

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Should I use stored procedure for this? Can you show me an example please?

Answer (score 1):

If your words are always separated by spaces, you could use [`regexp_count`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/15/functions-string.html):

```
select regexp_count('while swam is interesting','\S+')
```

As mentioned in a comment, you should never store in a table something that can be easily computed at run time, otherwise you increase the risk of inconsistent data.

Comment: Here is another regex (for fun) `select regexp_count ('while swam is interesting', '(^\w|\w$|\W\w|\w\W).')`